# Debugging `dockerd` with `dlv` fails

Tags: docker, go, debugging, delve, docker-daemon

I am trying to understand something inside `dockerd` using `dlv` debugger. Unfortunately, every time I am trying to do that I am facing errors. I can't do `dlv exec` nor `dlv attach`.

The following diff shows some changes I applied to `docker/docker` to make sure that some go optimizations are avoided and debugging is possible:

```
diff --git i/hack/make/.binary w/hack/make/.binary
index d56e3f3..e6835fa 100644
--- i/hack/make/.binary
+++ w/hack/make/.binary
@@ -84,6 +84,7 @@ hash_files() {
        go build \
                -o "$DEST/$BINARY_FULLNAME" \
                "${BUILDFLAGS[@]}" \
+               -gcflags="all=-N -l" \
                -ldflags "
                $LDFLAGS
                $LDFLAGS_STATIC_DOCKER
```

I also modified `dockerd-rootless.sh` to make sure I don't use plain `exec` but `dlv exec dockerd -- $@`. Unfortunately every time I get the following error:

```
Could not create config directory: mkdir /root/.config: permission denied.could not launch process: could not get .debug_frame section: could not find .debug_frame section
```

The same error happens when I try to `dlv attach docker-pid`:

```
could not attach to pid 228089: could not get .debug_frame section: could not find .debug_frame section
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing it?

INFO:

```
uname -a

Linux host 5.6.8-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 29 19:10:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
go version

go version go1.13.10 linux/amd64
```

```
dlv version

Delve Debugger
Version: 1.4.0
Build: $Id: 67422e6f7148fa1efa0eac1423ab5594b223d93b $
```

```
docker version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b7f0
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:27:05 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was due to `LDFLAGS` and the presence of `-w` flag used while executing `go build`.